# css create rounded shadow under a square image

Tags: html, css, image, shadow

Is there a way to create a rounded shadow effect underneath a square image such as the one in the image?

I was also looking at [this website](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/) which says that this sort of effect is possible, but their description of the code implementation is really ambiguous.

[image]

Comment: This are the possibilities but with jQuery Shadow: http://syddev.com/jquery.shadow/
This are the possibitlies with Css3: http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/

Comment: Just view the source of the page.

Comment: can you please explain to me how the 'Raised' box shadow effect can be implemented onto an image. I only ask this because their code is hard to follow. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I basically used the spread property of the Box Shadow to shrink its width smaller than the element which it was associated with. It is the fourth px element in this code:

```
box-shadow: 0px 30px 40px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

I then moved the shadow down vertically until I was happy with how much shadow it was showing.

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6yYaY/)

Comment: don't forget to add `-webkit-box-shadow` see also: http://www.prowebdesign.ro/round-brush-like-responsive-drop-shadows-with-css3-and-no-images/

Comment: 2014 Note: -webkit-box-shadow has been deprecated; simply use box-shadow